# Solving Algebra involving surds

Tags: linear-algebra

Could someone explain this?

$$\sqrt{125} + \sqrt{20} = \sqrt{80} + \sqrt{x}$$

Solve for $x$.

Much appreciated. Please explain in full detail as it's quite hard to understand otherwise.

Comment: What's wrong with $$x=\left(\sqrt{124}+\sqrt{20}-\sqrt{80}\right)^2$$ are you sure this is the equation you mean?

Comment: Well it's simply (approximatively) 
$$
11.35 + 4.47 = 8.94 + \sqrt{x}
$$
Which is quite trival to solve, right ?

Comment: @vrugtehagel: probably the question wants this expression to be simplified using the distributive law.

Comment: @zubzub: That is an unhelpful comment. Presumably the question is not about finding an approximate solution.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip I don't see a good reason to assume either of those two things.

Comment: The question is on a non calculator paper, the solution is after a square root as an answer.

Comment: @Kaynex Common sense. In spite of being tagged "linear algebra", most probably this is a question for junior high school or so. Unless it is a very unusual thing, they are not interested in doing rational approximations to rather irrational numbers, but as Grumpy mentioned the wanted solution most probably is about rationalizing irrational expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation is equivalent to $$5\sqrt{5}+2\sqrt{5}=4\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{x}$$ 
So $$\sqrt{x}=3\sqrt{5}=\sqrt{45}\implies x=45$$

Answer (score 1):

The original equation is

$$5\sqrt5+2\sqrt5=4\sqrt5+\sqrt x\implies\sqrt x=3\sqrt5=\sqrt{45}\ldots\ldots$$

Answer (score 1):

We can solve for $x$ by doing the following.

$$\sqrt{125}+\sqrt{20}=\sqrt{80}+\sqrt{x},$$ 
$$5\sqrt{5}+2\sqrt{5}=4\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{x},$$
$$3\sqrt{5}=\sqrt{x},$$
$$(\sqrt{x})^2=(3\sqrt{5})^2,$$
$$x=45.$$

Answer (score 0):

Well, first we should note that $$\sqrt{80}=\sqrt{16\cdot5}=\sqrt{16}\sqrt{5}=4\sqrt{5}$$
similarly,
$$\sqrt{20}=\sqrt{4\cdot5}=\sqrt{4}\sqrt{5}=2\sqrt{5}$$
and
$$\sqrt{125}=\sqrt{25\cdot5}=\sqrt{25}\sqrt{5}=5\sqrt{5}$$

so that the equation becomes

$$5\sqrt{5} + 2\sqrt{5} = 4\sqrt{4} + \sqrt{x}$$

Now subtract $4\sqrt{5}$ from both sides to obtain
$$5\sqrt{5} - 2\sqrt{5} =\sqrt{x}$$

Which simplifies to

$$3\sqrt{5} = \sqrt{x}$$

And note that

\begin{align}
3\sqrt{5}&= \sqrt{x}\\
(3\sqrt{5})^2&=x\\
3^2\sqrt{5}^2&=x\\
9\cdot 5&=x\\
45&=x
\end{align}

So that we find the solution

> $$x=45$$

Comment: Hi mate, I don't know the correct answer but I definitely know that it shouldn't be that. It should be all under one square root symbol.

Comment: It is indeed not the correct answer. The question (now) states to find $x$ when $\sqrt{125}+\sqrt{20}=\sqrt{80}+\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: The question was edited. I used to say $124$ instead of $125$. I'll edit my answer.